# REST API design aggregate

Tags: api, rest, aggregate

We are creating api on employee manage app. So there is schedule in interface, where we have to show all shifts in table, for every user per row. Farther, there is summary for every user (per row) and day (per column). Should we create one big aggregate call like:

```
GET /api/locations/{id}/shedule
```

which will return all employees, shifts, summaries etc. Or maybe should we smash that to several collections like:

```
GET /api/locations/{id}/shifts
GET /api/locations/{id}/events
GET /api/locations/{id}/summary
GET /api/employee/{id}/summary?date_from={date_from}&date_from={date_to}
```

For me, second option is more flexible and there is no reason to create new abstract resource, which is shedule. In my opinion it is clearly part of interface layer and should not affect on API design.

On the other hand the big aggregate is more optimal, becouse there will be less database calls and it's easy to cache.

How do you think? Is there any source, kind of article, which can I rely on?

Comment: Do you need all the information in 1 batch always? go with /schedule, if not, go with seperate

Comment: @TimCastelijns Well, all of them at once we need only once so far. But I'm pretty sure some of that collections will be needed in future features. Question is more about REST standard at all than this specific implementation

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing RESTful or unRESTful about either approach. The semantics of URIs is irrelevant to REST. What really matters is how the clients obtain the URIs. If they are looking up URI patterns in documentation and filling up values instead of using links, the API is not RESTful.

With that in mind, I'd say the approach that is more consistent with your business and your ecosystem of applications is the best one. Don't be afraid to create aggregate resources if you feel the need to.

Comment: Yes, agreed! It depends of the granularity of data you want to provide to the API client. The way to update the elements can also give you some hints... Hope it helps